# POSTGRESQL Selecting only duplicate accounts that have at least one duplicate phone number

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I would like to get this sample data (POSTGRESQL):

```
uuid       email       phone_number        
    1   a@gmail.com        111
    2   a@gmail.com        111
    3   a@gmail.com        112
    4   b@gmail.com        222
    5   b@gmail.com        222
    6   c@gmail.com        333
    7   d@gmail.com        444
    8   d@gmail.com        445
    9   d@gmail.com        446
```

And eliminate all the:

1. non duplicate email entries (in the example the uuid = 6)
2. rows with duplicate emails but all the phone numbers are different
   (in the example, uuid = 7,8,9)

And mantain:

1. one of the rows with duplicate email entries and all phone numbers equal (in the example, uuid = 4,5)
2. one of the rows with duplicate email entries and at least two phone numbers equal (in the example, uuid = 1,2,3)

The result data would be

```
      email       phone_number        
   a@gmail.com        111
   b@gmail.com        222
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to filter by the phone and cpf when phone and cpf are equal, but I lose a lot because it goes okay when there are 2 dupe accounts, but with 3 or more it is not accurate

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by` clause with `having`

```
select email, phone_number 
from table t
group by email, phone_number  
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, you want:

```
select email, max(phone_number)
from t
group by email
having count(*) > count(distinct phone_number) and
       count(*) > 1;
```